# Problem with UTF-8. The accent is printing wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I'm new to Python (version 3.9) and I'm trying to read and print a CSV file, however, when it comes to printing, the centering appears wrong. I've used 'UTF-8', 'latin' and 'ISO-8859-1'. But none worked.

My code:

```
import io
import csv

with io.open(filename.csv, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
# process Unicode text
with io.open(filename.csv, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)

    print(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

printing:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf"N\xc3\xbamero,""Descri\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o"",""Fonte"",""Situa\xc3\xa7\xc3\xa3o""
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: try use text.decode() instead of text.encode('utf-8')

Comment: Use `print(text)` instead of `print(text.encode())`. By calling `text.encode()`, you convert `text` from `str` to `bytes`, and then `print()` converts it back to `str` (but in a not-so-clever way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, input file contains [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) `b'\xef\xbb\xbf'`. Apply `utf_8_sig` — [UTF-8 codec with BOM signature](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig) (an optional UTF-8 encoded BOM at the start of the data will be skipped).

```
import io
import csv

with io.open(filename.csv, 'r', encoding='utf_8_sig') as f:
    text = f.read()
# process Unicode text
with io.open(filename.csv, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)

print(text)
# "Número","Descrição","Fonte","Situação"
```

Not sure about return value as your input and output example is not [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Python 3 doesn't need `io.open` unless you are looking for backward compatibility with Python 2.  `open` has the same syntax.

Comment: @MarkTolonen yes, I know. The `io` module official docs say literally about [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html#io.open):  _This is an alias for the builtin `open()` function_.

Answer (score 0):

I changed print `(text.encode (utf-8))` by `print(text)` and it worked.